# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (786,1080,1920) into shape (786,)

Tags: python

I am getting the error `"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (786,1080,1920)" into shape (786)`,  My code is:

```
   def set_state (self):
        last_bbox = []
        state = []
        
        
        image = dg.load_img()
        GT_boxes,last_boxes = dg.get_box_data()
        gt_box = dg.get_data()
        
        for i in range(len(last_boxes)):
            last_xmin = last_boxes[i][0]
            last_ymin = last_boxes[i][1]
            last_xmax = last_boxes[i][2]
            last_ymax = last_boxes[i][3]

            x,y,w,h = dg.get_demansion(last_xmin,last_ymin,last_xmax,last_ymax)

            last_bbox.append((x,y,w,h))

        last_bbox = np.array(last_bbox)
        print(image.shape)
        print(last_bbox.shape)
        print(gt_box.shape)

        state.append(image)
        state.append(last_bbox)
        state.append(gt_box)
        
        state = np.array(state)


        return state
```

**output**

> image.shape = (786, 1080, 1920)

> last_bbox.shape = (786, 4)

> gt_box.shape = (786, 4)

I am getting the error :

```
    state = np.array(state)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (786,1080,1920) into shape (786,)
```

Comment: Right, those arrays cannot be combined.  What were you expecting that to do?  What shape did you expect the result to have?

Comment: I wanted to have those three arrays in one array at a time.

Comment: For what purpose?  Numpy does not allow that. You can't mix a 3D array and a 2D array.  If you're just trying to store it, either leave it as a Python list, or create an object class with those things as members.